# SCSS Output Styles Do Not Work

Tags: css, sass, minify

Style page is not minimized.

Is there a way to run:

```
sass --watch scss:css --style compressed
```

Ruby

```
ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [x64-mingw32]
```

SASS Verison

```
sass -v
Sass 3.5.0-rc.1 (Bleeding Edge)
```

Comment: We have no idea what you are talking about. What program are you using? what tools are you using? Without that we cannot help you out.

Comment: Start Command Prompt with Ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it for compressed your scss file to css

sass -w scss/style.scss:css/style.css --style compressed

Comment: Thank you. The problem has improved.